# Swift: how to load users from firebase with skipping liked users from another child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

- hello, I have a Firebase that its structured as follows:

  ```
  1. **Likes**:
     -*user1*
        -user3: "true"
        -user5: "false"
        - ....
     -*user3*
        -user1: "true"
        -...
  2. **Users**:    
     -*user1*:
       -name: "Jack"
       -email: "jackmail@mail.ml"
       -...    
     -*user2*:
       -name: "..."
       -email: "..."
       -...    
     -*user3*:
       -...    
     -*user4*:
       -...    
     -*user5*:
       -...    
     -*user6*:
       -...
  ```

So, I'm looking to load Users thats not in **Likes** Child...
(Load Users thats not Liked Before..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a concrete example

```
posts
  post_0
    likes
      user_0: true
      user_2: true
  post_1
    likes
      user_1: true

users
  user_0
    name: "Gilligan"
    likes:
      post_0: true
  user_1
    name: "Mary Ann"
    likes
      post_1: true
  user_2
    name: "Thurston"
    likes:
      post_0: true
  user_3
    name: "Ginger"
    likes: false
```

Then query the users node for all users where likes is false, which would be Ginger in this case.

```
   let query = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "likes").queryEqual(toValue: false)
   query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
   }
```

Comment: I have a list of users in Users child ordred for each user by id... and for each users if liked or dislikes orher users it adding in Likes child by his ID. So i have to load all users without loading the users that liked or disliked by current user... thank you

Comment: my database how its looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311096/ios-swift-firebase-loading-data

Comment: @Sotradias My suggested code and structure will do what your want: It will load the users that have not liked any posts before. Your structure doesn't lend itself to getting that data with a single query or without loading a lot of data.

Comment: Lets make the user1 the current user okay, user1 likes user3 and user5 (the structure above...). So i went to load all users without user3 and user4 ... @Jay thank u

Comment: @Sotradias In the structure in your question, you have user1 liking user3 (true) but not liking user5 (false)? If you want to load users that have not liked before (as in your question), my code does just that; any users who have not liked before will have likes set to false and it's a simple query from there. If that isn't what you are asking, perhaps your can clarify the question with more clear data. Otherwise it will probably be closed as it's unclear what is being asked.

Comment: Yes i know, i went to load all users unless the users have liked or unliked (user have true value or false whatever his value ...true or false).. loading all users unless the users in the LIKES chlid  for the curent user.., for example if the current user is user1 : load all user unless user3 and user5 whatever his value..

Comment: You answer is not wrong, but maybe i didn't explain well the desired result: what i'm trying to to i s to get the users under users node and exclude the ones that exist in likes node, thanks @Jay